# Website always flags it using an outdated browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the site https://anichart.net/ in order to use the information to build a schedule from the information.  The problem is that the site is always detecting an outdated browser (shows http://outdatedbrowser.com).

```
    <div class=noscript>We\'re sorry but AniChart requires Javascript. 
    <br>Please enable Javascript or <a 
    href=http://outdatedbrowser.com>upgrade to a modern web browser</a>. 
    </div></noscript><div class="noscript modern-browser" style="display: 
    none">Sorry, AniChart requires a modern browser.<br>Please <a 
    href=http://outdatedbrowser.com>upgrade to a newer web browser</a>.</div>
```

I have tried a regular request and have also tried forcing the user agent, shown below.

```
    import requests

    self.url = 'https://anichart.net/Winter-2019'

    headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/72.0.3626.109'}

    self.page = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers)

    print(self.page.content)
```

I understand that the site uses javascript and the Requests module won't reference the javascript generated portion of the site unless I use other tools with it or potentially Selenium.  My browsers are up-to-date so this should not be returning an outdated browser result.

This was working just fine a few days ago but it looks like they did just update their site so they may have added something that prevents automated requests on the site.

Edit:

Selenium Code below:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    url = 'https://anichart.net/Winter-2019'

    website = webdriver.Chrome()

    website.get(url)

    print(website.page_source)

    html_after_JS = website.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

    print(html_after_JS)
```

Comment: You can get a real web browser that doesn't make this message show up and simply copy its headers to your request. There are sites that let you see the headers your browser sends.

Comment: The "outdated browser" warning your seeing is because of missing Javascript — the  part just before is in `noscript` tags, and this part is probably removed by JS when the app itself loads.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the browser detection.

`requests` simply does render JavaScript (as you seem to know already), and most sites nowadays uses front-end Javascript libraries to render content. And some more sites use Javascript detection to prevent bots from scraping the pages...

You instead will need to use a tool like Selenium, which will open a headless, "modern" browser, of your choice, and you can scrape the page from there. But you have not shown that code, so it might make sense to ask about that instead?

Or, better yet, they have an API - https://github.com/AniList/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs

> The AniList & AniChart websites themselves run on the Api, so everything you can do on the sites, you can do via the Api.

Comment: I have tried Selenium as well and got the same results.  I added the code to my question.  However, I will review the API you posted as well.